C# - How to compare multiple nullable values to check if those that have value are equal?
What is the easiest way to check multiple nullable values, to know if those that are not null are equal?
double? a = null
double? b = 2;
double? c = 3.5;

should return false
double? a = 2.5
double? b = 2;
double? c = 2;

should return false
double? a = null
double? b = 2;
double? c = 2;

should return true
double? a = 4.5;
double? b = 4.5;
double? c = 4.5;

should return true

What do you mean by "easiest"?

What if all three are null, is that a true or a false for you?

@GSerg: good question... in this case, if all three are null, that would be a true... (I think, to be honest I dont quite remember the exact case I needed this). In fact I think I had a previous if-else to check for that before calling this code... as I was only interested in the case where not all were null...

@Enigmativity: err... "less difficult"? as in "less code needed" I guess...

@patsy2k In this case you shouldn't have accepted the answer, because it will give you a false if all three are null.

This seems fairly "easy" to me:
bool NonNullsAllEqual(params double?[] inputs) =>
    inputs.Where(y => y != null).Distinct().Count() == 1;


Easy and elegant XD. Perfect. Thanks mate

@patsy2k - It would be great if you responded to the comments on the question.

You are right, sorry. Done.
